# How to rowCount a null data

Tags: php, pdo

I want user to have valid email thats why i check if the comform there email.

I get the username and count the rows who have that username and Activation set to NULL,but if i echo the rowCount = 0 but there is a such a row

```
$checkMail = $dbh->prepare("SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE username =:username 
AND Activation=''");
$checkMail->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$checkMail->execute();
echo $exist = $checkMail->rowCount();
```

Comment: What is the datatype of Activation ?

Answer (score 0):

If Activation is really NULL, your query should be:

```
SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE username =:username AND Activation IS NULL
```

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL' at line 1

Comment: Probably there is some problems with $_POST["username"] value. If it's not set, the sql query will be incorrect